# what does it mean: if (number)

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have:

```
float number = 2.5;
if (number) cout << "1\n";
else        cout << "2\n";
```

what does it mean: `if (number)`? maybe if the number is initialized?

Comment: I suppose that beginner's C++ tutorial didn't have a chapter or two on the `if` statement and expressions, did it... >.<

Comment: Hm, interesting, I thought `if (number)` only works for integral `number`.

Comment: @afriza No, it works on any scalar.

Comment: And now someone's upvoting this... Blehh!

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks :) I wrote a program to check if it works on a struct and it isnt. `could not convert 'a' from 'A' to 'bool'`. Could you please tell me what are the types which qualify as scalar? Any non-object type?

Comment: @thefourtheye In C, those are integral, floating-point and pointer types. Not sure about C++ (there may be some subtle unintuitive difference, as always in C++...)

Comment: @H2CO3 there is the can of worms that is non-explicit conversion operators for user defined types. Your class could have a conversion to `double`, which in an `if()` context would convert all the way to `bool`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yap, I *told* you there's something additional stuff going on in C++ :)

Comment: for floating-point types, when will it mean `false`? any other values than `0.f`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any non-zero value , then it is true. In some systems , numeric values are returned to ascertain if the process succeeded or failed . Most of the implementations return `0` as success code and `-1` as failure code. If a process succeeded then all you need to know about is that it is a success so `0` , if it failed then the system can send any non-zero error code for debugging. But don't rely on it for any specific implementation.

I believe `0` was chosen to implicitly signify `false` , because in Boolean arithmetic they behave kinda similar.

```
0|1=1
0&1=0
false|true = true
false&true = false
```

Answer (score 3):

It means that the number is 'truthy'; which for numbers means that it is not 0.

To more expressively show that you are using a non-boolean type's 'truthiness', one could write

```
if (!!number)
```

which will first convert the value to it's boolean negative, and then negate it to represent the numbers truth value.

Comment: @thefourtheye That's not one operator, that's the `!` operator applied twice.

Answer (score 1):

If condition becomes true for any value other than zero. So if `number` is not zero, the printed value is `1` else `2`

Answer (score 1):

No, it just checks if the value (when converted to `int`) is non-zero, which in C is regarded as being "true".

It's not possible to look at the value of a `float` and determine if it's "initialized" or not, all you have are the bits of the `float` and there is no guarantee that any particular pattern is present in un-initialized variables (if that was the case, then the location woul not, in my opinion, be un-initialized).

You can do this with e.g. pointers as well, you often see code like:

```
char *s = malloc(1024);
if( s )
{
  /* use the buffer, allocation succeeded */
}
```

instead of the more verbose (but, in my opinion, clearer):

```
if( s != NULL )
{
}
```

the meaning (and often the generated code) is exacly the same.